# CSS: dynamic Float Layout has set height no matter what

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to use this format to create a css "table" within my layout.
However defining the height in any of the elements still doesn't change the height of 
the "table" with the floats in it.
I want the table to remain dynamic, but I can't find a way to make this height shrink because at the moment it is leaving a large amount of blank space at the bottom after the content in the floats.

Thanks for any help!

[Js Fiddle Showing Gap](http://jsfiddle.net/NAA8w/2/)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see the problem you describe: [JS Fiddle reproduction of posted code](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NAA8w/). Are you able to clarify at all?

Comment: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NAA8w/2/)  Sorry it wasn't floating with the code I posted.  So I just posted all my css and html in there and you can see the problem I am having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#right { height:775px; } <----- is this the gap you're trying to eliminate?`

If so, it's nested inside your main content block(s). Removing it, will allow the height to expand with content.

http://jsfiddle.net/NAA8w/3/

Comment: That fixed my problem!  I didn't realize I was an idiot and had given to elements the same name.  Thank you so much!